# Display image of the customer on a jlabel using a link.saved in database

Tags: java, string, image, swing, jdbc

In my Java Application the code below working fine. But I want to display the photo of customer also in addition to them. I do not want to store the photo as a blob in database. I just want to store the photo in some local drive and display it in jLabel. Can anyone help me?

```
try{
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:/gymsoft/data", "APP", "app");
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
    String query ="SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CODE = '"+jTextField1.getText()+"' ";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    if(rs.next()) {
        String w = rs.getString("NAME");
        String x = rs.getString("CODE");
        TF1.setText(w);
        TF2.setText(x);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Not Found!!");
    }
} catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error In Connection!!");
}
```

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML. To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.  2) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: *"Can anyone help me?"*  I'm not sure.  Did you have a ***specific*** question?

Comment: look at FileIO, there are XxxStream, use that up/downloading lagre files or Images, could be depends of data type is set in database for the column

Answer (score 2):

Showing an image in a `JLabel` is certainly possible. Retrieving an image from a link is possible as well. However, I found no attempts of any of those in your code.

What I did found in your code is

- vulnerability to SQL injection. When the user inputs in `jTextField1` something like

  ```
  3';drop database app`
  ```

  you can say goodbye to your database
- mixing of database queries and updates of UI components. A database query is typically slow so it should not be performed on the same thread as the thread which updates the UI. Further, all Swing components should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread so moving the whole code to a worker thread is not an option. You need to separate those. Consult the [concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) guide for more information
- You forgot to close the `Connection`. When you add such a `close` statement, do it in a `finally` block

Comment: +1 for finding vulnerabilities even if not asked, good points :)